# How to read output_content from azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have defined an azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment **my_rm** which has ARM template source:

```
{
  ...
  "parameters": {...  }, 
  "resources": [ ...  ],
  "outputs": {
    "db_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "test_value"
    } 
  }
}
```

I would like to use this output in terraform, like:

```
output "db_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment.my_rm.output_content["db_name"]
}
```

Unfortunately above definition returns empty value.

What is the correct way to define the output in terraform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [output_content](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/resource_group_template_deployment.html#output_content) exports the **JSON Content** of the Outputs of the ARM Template Deployment.

After my validation, you could output the content with

```
output "db_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment.my_rm.output_content
}
```

Then run `terraform apply`, you will see the output result, then you can change to filter the result with

```
output "db_name" {
  value = jsondecode(azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment.my_rm.output_content).db_name.value
}
```

Please note that the `db_name` is not the same declaration `db_name` in your terraform code, it really should match the output JSON key in the first above step.

For example,

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately if you add both outputs at once `terraform plan` not work. See this:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/29292